# Python ctypes - Memory read Error when calling a function in a DLL

Tags: python, ctypes

I'm a beginner to python and ctypes and i'm writing a script to control a PCMCIA device, the driver provided by the vendor is a dll file. I just want to call functions in it, but i just don't know why I keep getting a [The instruction at "0x7c9108d3" referenced memory at "0xfffffff8". The memory could not be "read"]. Here is the documents say:

```
//declaration
XLstatus xlGetDriverConfig(XLdriverConfig *pDriverConfig) 

typedef struct s_xl_driver_config  { 
    unsigned int      dllVersion; 
    unsigned int      channelCount;  
    unsigned int      reserved[10]; 
    XLchannelConfig   channel[XL_CONFIG_MAX_CHANNELS]; 
} XLdriverConfig; 

//types
typedef struct s_xl_channel_config { 

    char            name [XL_MAX_LENGTH + 1]; 
    unsigned char   hwType; 
    unsigned char   hwIndex;  
    unsigned char   hwChannel; 
    unsigned short  transceiverType;  
    unsigned int    transceiverState; 
    unsigned char   channelIndex;    

    XLuint64      channelMask;      //here  
    unsigned int  channelCapabilities; 
    unsigned int  channelBusCapabilities; 
    unsigned char isOnBus; 
    unsigned int  connectedBusType; 
    XLbusParams   busParams; 
    unsigned int  driverVersion; 
    unsigned int  interfaceVersion; 
    unsigned int  raw_data[10]; 
    unsigned int  serialNumber; 
    unsigned int  articleNumber; 
    char          transceiverName [XL_MAX_LENGTH + 1]; 
    unsigned int  specialCabFlags; 
    unsigned int  dominantTimeout; 
    unsigned int  reserved[8]; 
} XLchannelConfig; 

typedef unsigned __int64 XLuint64;

typedef struct {                                                                         
  unsigned int busType;
  union {
    struct {
      unsigned int bitRate;
      unsigned char sjw;
      unsigned char tseg1;
      unsigned char tseg2;
      unsigned char sam;  // 1 or 3
      unsigned char outputMode;
    } can;
    struct {
      unsigned int  activeSpeedGrade;
      unsigned int  compatibleSpeedGrade;
    } most;
    unsigned char raw[32];
  }data;
} XLbusParams;
```

There is my python script below:

```
from ctypes import *
vxlapi = WinDLL("vxlapi.dll")
PyxlGetDriverConfig = vxlapi.xlGetDriverConfig

class PyXLchannelConfig(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("Pyname",c_char*32),
                ("PyhwType",c_ubyte),
                ("PyhwIndex",c_ubyte),
                ("PyhwChannel",c_ubyte),
                ("PytransceiverType",c_ushort),
                ("PytransceiverState",c_ushort),
                ("PyconfigError",c_ushort),
                ("PychannelIndex",c_ubyte),
                ("PychannelMask",c_longlong),
                ("PychannelCapabilities",c_uint),
                ("PychannelBusCapabilities",c_uint),

                ("PyisOnBus",c_ubyte),
                ("PyconnectedBusType",c_uint),
                ("PybusParams",c_uint),

                ("PydriverVersion",c_uint),
                ("PyinterfaceVersion",c_uint),
                ("Pyraw_data",c_uint*10),

                ("PyserialNumber",c_uint),
                ("PyarticleNumber",c_uint),

                ("PytransceiverName",c_char*32),

                ("PyspecialCabFlags",c_uint),
                ("PydominantTimeout",c_uint),
                ("PydominantRecessiveDelay",c_ubyte),
                ("PyrecessiveDominantDelay",c_ubyte),
                ("PyconnectionInfo",c_ubyte),
                ("PycurrentlyAvailableTimestamps",c_ubyte),
                ("PyminimalSupplyVoltage",c_ubyte),
                ("PymaximalSupplyVoltage",c_ubyte),
                ("PymaximalBaudrate",c_uint),
                ("PyfpgaCoreCapabilities",c_ubyte),
                ("PyspecialDeviceStatus",c_ubyte),
                ("PychannelBusActiveCapabilities",c_ushort),
                ("PybreakOffset",c_ushort),
                ("PydelimiterOffset",c_ushort),
                ("Pyreserved",c_uint*3)
                ]

class PyXLdriverConfig(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("PydllVersion",c_uint),
                ("PychannelCount",c_uint),
                ("Pyreserved",c_uint*10),
                ("Pychannel",PyXLchannelConfig*64)
                ]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    drivercfg = PyXLdriverConfig()
    PyxlGetDriverConfig(byref(drivercfg))
```

Could you help me out of this, Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see at least two differences:

```
unsigned int    transceiverState; 
("PytransceiverState",c_ushort),

XLbusParams   busParams; 
("PybusParams",c_uint),
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few mistakes in your code, but for the most part it is there.

I am assuming the following defines appear in the original C.

```
#define XL_CONFIG_MAX_CHANNELS (64)
#define XL_MAX_LENGTH (31)
```

though I get the feeling that `XL_MAX_LENGTH` is probably defined to 32.

I think the problem stems from your ctypes structure and your C structure being different sizes and so your library is reading/writing to memory it is not allowed to access.

These are the pertinent problems:

- There are a few wrong types in the ctypes structure; `PytransceiverState` should be `c_uint`, not `c_ushort`; `PyconfigError` should be `c_ulonglong`, not `c_longlong`); etc.
- There are quite a few erroneous fields; what is the C equivalent of `PyconfigError`; where do all the ctypes fields after `PydominantTimeout` come from?
- You don't define the ctypes structure equivalent of `XLBusParams`, instead using a `c_uint`. Since `XLBusParams` is at least 45 bytes in size and you instead provide 4 bytes, bad things will happen.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into this wrapper for vxlapi for python:
http://code.google.com/p/pycanlibxl/ ?

Be aware that it does not implement all vxlapi.dll functions and header file constants and enumerations.
Also some function definations have default values which might not suite yours (such as interface type).

Comment: Great.Thanks a lot!! That saves lots of time for me.